# How to check if a row has data and conditional format from there?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, gs-conditional-formatting

I'm trying to code a Google Sheet to check if a row has any data in it, and then use conditional formatting to color-code another cell in that row. How could I do this?

Screenshots are [here](https://imgur.com/a/f2MjLCP). The idea is that the cells in column B will turn red if there is any data in the same row. So in this example, B2 would stay green, B3 would turn red (automatically, with no text input), and B4 and B5 would stay blank, because there is no data in that row.

This sheet is linked to a Google Form, so it needs to be able to update automatically.

(I'm a beginner to Google Sheets, so I'm not familiar with the necessary code at all.)

Edit: [Here's](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18wuIKmL8YiD1zyIpzknxL8ZMuc1Oi3ITaQXa6V17ZpY/edit?usp=sharing) a copy of my sheet.

Comment: Done! Copy is linked in post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try simple custom formula:

```
=A2<>""
```

[image: 0]

### [spreadsheet demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WhFatJNkJ9ASuBRmtOWqDblr6TYyRoI462dbttxmAeE/copy)